# rightbelow not exhibiting the correct behavior

Tags: terminal, vim-windows, ex-mode

I am not seeing the correct behavior when I use the `rightbelow` command. If I run `:vertical term` then a terminal opens in a vertical split (terminal on the left, existing pane on the right), but the new window is on the left. If I run `:rightbelow term` then a terminal opens on the bottom of the screen (a horizontal split), not a vertical split as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

"Rightbelow" (or "belowright") here means "right *or* below whichever is applicable".

So in your case you have to type all three words `vert rightb term` (or `below vertical term` - the order doesn't really matter).

Also, you can do `set splitright` and/or `set splitbelow` to change vim's default behaviour for all commands.